# How to click image using Sikuli in Robot Framework

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework, sikuli

I am new in using Sikuli and I don't know what to do.

I did some simple test that sikuli will click an image. But it is failing This is what it says.

*The last error was: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.sikuli.script.Finder$Finder2*

```html
Click                          test.png
```

Also suite teardown is failing.

*Suite teardown failed:
org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: fatal: Java arch must be 64 Bit (java 8 version 1.8 vm 25.241-b07 class 52.0 arch null)*

```html
Suite Teardown    Close Application    SikuliLibrary
```

These are the versions I am using

java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

robotframework 3.1.2
seleniumlibrary==4.1.0
SikuliLibrary==1.0.8
selenium - 3.141.0

Comment: If you paste a small but complete example, we could try to replicate your errors. How do you initialize SikuliLibrary? You don't need that Teardown, the library is closed after use.

Comment: it is okay now. I realized that I installed 32bit java instead of 64bit.